# backup of Domain controller on Jboss eap6

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I have 4 remote jboss eap6 with deployed application. First one is working as Domain Controller. In host.xml I declared backup of DC (example):

```
<domain-controller>  
​    <remote security-realm="ManagementRealm">  
​          <discovery-options>  
​              <static-discovery name="primary" host="172.16.81.100" port="9999"/>  
​              <static-discovery name="backup" host="172.16.81.101" port="9999"/>  
​          </discovery-options>  
​    </remote>  
​</domain-controller>
```

For more info: [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/About_Domain_Controller_Failover.html)

What if 172.16.81.100 will be down? Is there any place on 172.16.81.101 to put actual copy of domain.xml with configuration of app-profiles and locally deployed HornetQ server? 
Is there possibility to change configuration of connection factories of any working profile during switching to backup?

Answer (score 0):

When you start "172.16.81.101" with --backup option domain.xml from DC will be cashed at remote HC under configuration directory with name 'domain.cached-remote.xml'. Once you reload HC it will act as DC for rest of the HC's. Can you please be specific what connection factory changes you want to done in cashed domain.xml file.

Comment: the problem is that after --backup part of messages from still-alive jboss servers was undiscovered by MDB's. eg. Producer on jboss3 is using CF (in-vm) so message is situated locally but any of MDB in cluster cannot consume this msg. I guess that is coused by mistake in backup domain config.

Comment: //edit  - the problem is after --backup command, part of messages from still-alive jboss servers was unconsumed by MDB's. eg. Producer on jboss3 is using CF (in-vm) so message is situated locally but any of MDB in cluster cannot consume this msg. I'm trying to find reason. The first shot was config of backup DC